# .corr results in ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, valueerror

I'm getting this very strange error when trying to follow the following exercise on using the corr() method in Python

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-corr/

Specifically, when I try to run the following code: `df.corr(method ='pearson')`

The error message offers no clue. I thought the corr() method was supposed to automatically ignore strings and empty values etc.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    df.corr(method='pearson')
  File "C:\Users\d.o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 10059, in corr
    mat = data.to_numpy(dtype=float, na_value=np.nan, copy=False)
  File "C:\Users\d.o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1838, in to_numpy
    result = self._mgr.as_array(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, na_value=na_value)
  File "C:\Users\d.o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1732, in as_array
    arr = self._interleave(dtype=dtype, na_value=na_value)
  File "C:\Users\d.o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1794, in _interleave
    result[rl.indexer] = arr
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Avery Bradley'
```

Comment: the last line there in that error message tells you that somehow your program ingested the term "Avery Bradley" ...  and oddly Avery Bradley does not appear to be correlated with any of the data!  (harrr harrrr.)  Anyhow, you will need to show the code that you are using to do this to troubleshoot if you still need help

Comment: Thanks @AirSquid. The code is literally just. import pandas as pd, df = pd.read_csv("nba.csv") and df.corr(method ='pearson') as per tutorial. Is it possible you can replicate the error? The corr() method is supposed to ignore strings and blanks for what I understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try to replicate this behavior, the `corr()` method works OK but spits out a warning (shown below) that warns that the ignoring of non-numeric columns will be removed in the future.  *Perhaps the future has arrived?*

I've got `pandas` version 1.5.3.

You may need to just specify which columns to use--which is actually a better way to do it rather than rely on pd to do this for you.  You can do that by just supplying a list of the columns of interest as an index (shown below.)

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: data = {'name': ['bob', 'cindy', 'tom'],
   ...:         'x'   : [ 1,     2,      3   ],
   ...:         'y'   : [ 6.5,   8.9,    12.0]}

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
    name  x     y
0    bob  1   6.5
1  cindy  2   8.9
2    tom  3  12.0

In [5]: df.describe()
Out[5]: 
         x          y
count  3.0   3.000000
mean   2.0   9.133333
std    1.0   2.757414
min    1.0   6.500000
25%    1.5   7.700000
50%    2.0   8.900000
75%    2.5  10.450000
max    3.0  12.000000

In [6]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   name    3 non-null      object 
 1   x       3 non-null      int64  
 2   y       3 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 200.0+ bytes

In [7]: df.corr(method='pearson')
<ipython-input-7-432dd9d4238b>:1: FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in DataFrame.corr is deprecated. In a future version, it will default to False. Select only valid columns or specify the value of numeric_only to silence this warning.
  df.corr(method='pearson')
Out[7]: 
          x         y
x  1.000000  0.997311
y  0.997311  1.000000

In [8]: df[['x', 'y']].corr(method='pearson')
Out[8]: 
          x         y
x  1.000000  0.997311
y  0.997311  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks! Works now. They must have stopped that old feature forcing people to specify columns.

Comment: Appears so.  Also, in the future, a good first place to look is to the documentation for the particular function you are trying to use.  The dox for this function in pandas 2.0 mentions this:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

Answer (score 37):

since pandas version 2.0.0 now you need to add `numeric_only=True` param to avoid the issue

Answer (score 3):

Try to use df.corr(numeric_only=True)
You'll get through it